# Python Turtle, draw text with on screen with larger font

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm using python turtle's write method to write text on the screen like this:

```
turtle.write("messi fan")
```

The size of the font is too small. How can I increase the size of font?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the optional `font` argument to [`turtle.write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.write), from the docs:

> `turtle.write(`*arg*, *move=False*, *align="left"*, *font=("Arial", 8, "normal")*`)`
>    **Parameters:**
>
> - **arg** – object to be written to the TurtleScreen
> - **move** – True/False
> - **align** – one of the strings “left”, “center” or right”
> - **font** – a triple (fontname, fontsize, fonttype)

So you could do something like `turtle.write("messi fan", font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))` to change the font size to 16 (default is 8).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use "bold" and "italic" instead of "normal" here. "Verdana" can be used for fontname..

But another question is this: How do you set the color of the text You write?

Answer: You use the turtle.color() method or turtle.fillcolor(), like this:

```
turtle.fillcolor("blue")
```

or just:

```
turtle.color("orange")
```

These calls must come before the turtle.write() command..

Answer (score 3):

To add bold, italic and underline, just add the following to the font argument:

`font=("Arial", 8, 'normal', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline')`

Comment: Please properly format your answer and avoid all caps wording https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting