# Could numbers appear in turtle window?

Tags: python, numbers, window, turtle-graphics

I have to do a coding task in school. I should list several numbers at random and complete the form of a turtle moving around on them. I would like to know how to list the numbers entered in the turtle window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter text then you need `turtle.write()`:

```
import random

a = [random.randint(0,10) for x in range(10)] # Generate 10 random numbers between 0 and 10

for i in a:
    turtle.forward(15)
    turtle.write(str(i))
```

You need to move the turtle otherwise all the numbers will appear on top of each other.

See [Python Turtle, draw text with on screen with larger font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141031/python-turtle-draw-text-with-on-screen-with-larger-font/15141107) and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?#turtle.write) for information on `turtle.write()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `write`

```
import turtle


if __name__ == '__main__':

    number = 42

    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.write(number)

    turtle.done()
```