# Can I use python to draw words in a specific font?

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics

I'm wondering if there are any functions that can allow me to draw words in turtle in any font?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `turtle.write` with the `font` argument, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141031/python-turtle-draw-text-with-on-screen-with-larger-font). For example:

```
turtle.write("Hello, world!", font=("Ariel", 20, "italic"))
```

The first element of the tuple passed for `font` is the font's name, the second argument is the size, and the third argument is whether it is bold, normal, or italic.